# How can I synchronize SVG animations?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make a rectangle move after 2 seconds of a circle's movement. I give each animation an ID, and then use ID with the begin event reference. However, nothing seems to work.

```
<svg width="800" height="600" style="background-color:black">

<circle id="circle" cx="30" cy="100" r="20" fill="gold" />

<animate
xlink:href="#circle"
attributeName="cx"
from="30"
to="750"
dur="4s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
id="circ-anim" />

<rect id="rectangle" x="50" y="400" width="50" height="20" fill="gold" />

<animate
xlink:href="#rectangle"
attributeName="x"
dur="3s"
from="50"
to="450
begin="circ-anim.begin + 2s"
id="rect-anim" />

</svg>
```

Comment: You see how `begin` is blue while all other attributes are red ? And once this typo is fixed, if you are using FF, then try to change your `#circ-anim` to `#circ_anim`. I think I remember `-` is not really enjoyed in an id.

Comment: You forgot `"` after `to="450`

Comment: @Kaiido thanx a lot, everything is perfect now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin). You can also add another begin point. I have put everything in a snippet like CeeJay said above.

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" style="background-color:black">

<circle id="circle" cx="30" cy="100" r="20" fill="gold" />

<animate
xlink:href="#circle"
attributeName="cx"
from="30"
to="750"
dur="4s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
id="circanim" />

<rect id="rectangle" x="50" y="400" width="50" height="20" fill="gold" />

<animate
xlink:href="#rectangle"
attributeName="x"
dur="3s"
from="50"
to="450"
begin="circanim.begin+2s"
id="rectanim"
repeatCount="indefinite"/>

</svg>
```